# Inject Implicit Ambient Typings via Visual Studio Code Extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to modify the ambient typings that intellisense uses for a user's typescript file(s) via my VS code extension, ie. the ones that get loaded via `lib.d.ts` and related auto-generated files.

eg. adding an implicit declaration of a `foo` function so that the user could write:

`foo();`

without the typechecker complaining!

I want my extension to inject some new ambient declarations into the global namespace upon load rather than have the user have to boilerplate each file with reference tags.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible but it will require you to update/write a file on/to disk. That's because tsserver only works with *real* files. Accepting that leaves you with the question where to put that file? It depends. To be really sure you must look at (and understand) what's in `tsconfig` or `jsconfig` - most likely tho you want to write to the `@types` or `typings` folders in which other tools also write. Often it might just work, but you might also be required to update the `tsconfig` file then, like adding the new file to the `include`-array.

Comment: Many thanks. I did a Q'n'D of this approach and it seems to work, just seems a shame that my extension pollutes the users folders/configs.. but maybe that's the rub

Comment: Have since realised you don't need to edit the tsconfig file. Writing a `d.ts` file into `typings` seems sufficient alone to have Intellisense pick up the definitions